# Why can't I set a time_t larger than 2^32?

Tags: c, fuse, time-t

I'm messing around with FUSE in C and I wanted to create a file that would appear to be created very far into the future. The custom stat() function I'm writing in FUSE writes to a struct stat* stbuf and I want to do something like

```
stbuf->st_ctime = (1 << 39) - 1;
```

To get a created date an absurdly long amount of time into the future.

I'm running this on a 64-bit linux system so I would expect my time_t to be a 64 bit value, and indeed, if I just printf("%d\n",(int) sizeof(x)); to test the size of time_t in my program I get 8. However, when I compile my code with warnings turned on, I get

```
warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
```

and the change time when I stat the file in the mounted filesystem I get

```
1969-12-31 15:59:59.000000000 -0800
```

as if the actual value was 0. Does anyone know why this is happening on a 64 bit system that should have a 64 bit time_t?

Comment: Try: `(1LL << 39) - 1`

Comment: @Mystical How about `(time_t)1<<39` ?

Comment: Next time try to make sense of the compiler warnings and errors. And, perhaps, get a good book on C or a copy of the C standard (or its draft).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `1 << 39` you are shifting an `int` and not a `time_t`.